# Android Studio WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading Toast Message Not Showing

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, toast, android-toast

I want to show toast message when the link is loading... it's working when i'm replace the toast message into **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** but another activity isn't showing the toast. how to do this for all my webview activity?

My code is:

```
 @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Toast.makeText(Bdnews24.this, "Loading...! Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
```